# Do the tags being merged can be dis-merged?

Tags: support, tagging, moderation

Suppose the tag B is merged into the tag A, if we later on find that the tag A and the tag B should keep them separate, can we do the dis-merge process?

Comment: There is a feature request at meta.SO: [Allow for tag synonym mappings to be reverted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175902/allow-for-tag-synonym-mappings-to-be-reverted) and [Need a rollback/undo for tag synonym merging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73316/need-a-rollback-undo-for-tag-synonym-merging). This post seems related, too: [Keep a log of merges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130873/keep-a-log-of-merges)

Answer (score 7):

No, the tag merge tool available to moderators is irreversible. It also doesn't create any revisions, it just rewrites history so that it looks like the retagged posts always had the now merged tag.

There might be a way that SE devs could reverse this manually on the database, but I don't know if they retain enough information to make this feasible.

Comment: Tis true, tag merging comes from the heart of the Ministry of Truth. "*He who controls the past controls the future. He who controls the present controls the past.*"

Comment: @Mad Scientist: Does this also mean that if we later on find that the name of tag B is more suitable that the name of tag A, rename one of the tag to the name of tag B is also impossible?